# How to make two lines (vertical and horizontal) in Latex titlepage

Tags: titles, thesis

I have small problem with creating engineering thesis template from word to LaTeX. I have no problem with creating geometry or setting up document commands but i don't really know how to make titlepage. I used \hrule and it's not working properly so can anyone help me with this? It's polish language but i only need these lines and logo (i have .png logo to paste into).

[image: Word document]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the code you have so far, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Unfortunally i have nothing useful. I have standard geometry code. \usepackage[left=4cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,top=3cm]{geometry}

Comment: You might use the `eso-pic` package to place whatever youwant on a page.

Comment: Is this page used inside the document or is this the cover (on the outside of a booklet or similar)? Because if this is the cover, it might be more practical to create it outside of LaTeX as a pdf and use the `pdfpages` package to import it at the start with `\includepdf`.

Comment: I had an idea. I can download plan PDF with no text inside and use this as \includepdf. I will try this idea. Thank you for this!

Comment: It's working great. Thank's for this idea!

Comment: Since you know Polish, this might be helpful https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=n6U_JOHhyzk&t=617s